# How to read Raspberry Pi 2 Sensor data using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-c++, raspberry-pi2, iot

I want to read Temperature sensor data (Dht222 & DH18B20) from Rasperry Pi2 (Windows 10). Basically, i am programmer and i have configure everything over Azure (i.e. IoT Hub, Event Hub, Notification Hub, iOS notification App) but since i am not EC guy, i am not sure how easily i can grab sensor data.

As reference, i am using this code: https://www.hackster.io/porrey/dht11-dht22-temperature-sensor-077790

Can anyone guide me something for this?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/ms-iot/Weather_Shield

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupPCRPI.htm

Then do these: https://github.com/drcrook1/MTPSolution/tree/master/MTPSolution/Documentation

I've been working up documentation on just this.  Give a whirl at "Connected Sensors" or "Intro to Sensors".  File issues if you run into problems.

Note: The Raspberry Pi does not have analog inputs similar to the Arduino, you need to interface with an Analog Digital Converter. This is the one I use in my documentation: https://www.adafruit.com/products/856

Note that Windows.IOT.Devices now includes support for MCP 3008 as well (not reflected in the code on my GitHub to date, but should change within a week or two).

You will need an official Pi Dongle or an Ethernet cable.  If you are using an Ethernet cable to bridge the network between your pi and the internet, ensure you go through my documentation on "Setting up the Pi" in my GitHub, your Pi needs to have DNS name resolution enabled to resolve the IoT Hub names.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have DHT22 sensor, which is digital only. Can u please help me out for that? Do you any sample code in c#?